# How to check values present in another dictionary keys

Tags: python

I have mandatory keys below

`fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']`

My dictionary is below

`body = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 3}, {'b1': 4, 'b2': 5, 'b3': 6}]}`

- In the `b` key of body I need to check fields all values are there or not
- if `fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b4']` the I need `False` because b4 is not present in `body['b']`
- if `body = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 3}, {'b1': 4, 'b2': 5, 'b4': 6}]}` then also i need `False` since b4 is not there in `fields`

My Code is below

`all((field in list(each.keys()) for each in body['b']) for field in fields)`

everytime i am getting `True`

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple `for` loop first?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i need to use list comprehension

Comment: Then write a loop first and then you can convert it mechanically to a list comprehension once it works correctly.

Comment: BTW what you have written is not a list comprehension.

Comment: can we use using ** (unpacking keys)

Comment: this should work......[False if False in [True if len(set(list(b.keys())+fields)) == len(b.keys()) else False for b in body['b']] else True]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting alway True becasue your code is doing `all` on a sequnce of generators.

As the other said, doing this with comprehension is NOT readable, thus not recomended.

If you need it anyway, you can use this:

```
body = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 3}, {'b1': 4, 'b2': 5, 'b3': 6}]}

fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b4']
out = all(all((f in each.keys() for f in fields)) for each in body['b'])
print(out)  #=> False

fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
out = all(all((f in each.keys() for f in fields)) for each in body['b'])
print(out)  #=> True
```

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a `lambda` function as below:

```
>>> fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
>>> body = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 3}, {'b1': 4, 'b2': 5, 'b3': 6}]}
>>> trueFalse = lambda x, y: [TorF in y for TorF in x].count(True) == len(x)
>>> all((trueFalse(list(x.keys()),fields)) for x in body["b"] )
True
>>>
>>> body = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 3}, {'b1': 4, 'b2': 5, 'b4': 6}]}
>>> all((trueFalse(list(x.keys()),fields)) for x in body["b"] )
False
```

Answer (score 1):

use set()

```
a = set(body['b'][0]) | set(body['b'][1])
b = set(fields)
c = a ^ b
print(c)
if len(c):
    print(False)
else:
    print(True)
```

Comment: or use frozenset()

Answer (score 1):

You can try it (reduce from functools):

1. Find all intersection keys in your dicts
2. Check your fields in intersection keys

```
intersection_keys = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, map(lambda d: set(d.keys()), body["b"]))
print([field in intersection_keys for field in fields])
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your datastructure

```
body = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 3}, {'b1': 4, 'b2': 5, 'b3': 6}]}
```

You can find all the keys that are present in the dicts in the `body['b']` list by:

```
# find all the keys that are present
present_fields = set(sum((list(bdict.keys()) for bdict in body['b']), []))
```

Then you can use set subtraction to find all the missing fields:

```
fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
required_fields = set(fields)
missing = required_fields - present_fields
print("MISSING2:", missing)
```

prints `set()` i.e. the empty set (no required fields are missing).

For the other example:

```
fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b4']
required_fields = set(fields)
missing = required_fields - present_fields
print("MISSING2:", missing)
```

it prints `{'b4'}` meaning that the `"b4"` field is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This works, if you really do need list comprehension:

```py
fields = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
body = {'a': 1, 'b': [{'b1': 1, 'b2': 2, 'b3': 3}, {'b1': 4, 'b2': 5, 'b4': 6}]}
print(False not in [i in fields for i in [item for subl in [list(d.keys()) for d in body['b']] for item in subl]])
```

Output:

```py
False
```

But at this point, you might as well use regular for loops.